# Why is $5^4=1 \mod 12$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to explain why $5^4=1 \mod 12$ without actually calculating $5^4 \mod 12$. Since $5^4=(5^2)^2$ and $5^2=1 \mod 12$, it seems obvious that $5^4=1^2=1 \mod 12$. I'm wondering if there is a better way to answer this question though. Is there some trick or fact I'm forgetting that would allow me to explain this without computing $5^2 \mod 12$?

Comment: You have a typo, $5^2 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 25$

Comment: You can also use [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a great deal to say - some calculation is necessary. But if you note that $\varphi(12)=4$ ie the count of the numbers less than $12$ which have no common factor with $12$ is $4$ (being $1,5,7,11$) it is immediate that any of these numbers raised to the power $4$ is equivalent to $1$ modulo $12$ from basic group theory, or the Fermat-Euler theorem.

You have to do as much work to prove those as to get the result you want. And in fact all the squares are equivalent to $1$, which is stronger than Fermat-Euler.

But Fermat-Euler applies in generality and saves work cross a range of cases.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfectly good proof to me. If you think that your factorization goes against the spirit of the question though, there is another approach. Consider the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z)^\times$. What’s the cardinality of this group? What does that tell you about *all* if it’s elements?

If you haven’t done any group theory yet, my hint is the same as the one that’s been commented: Use Euler’s Theorem.

Comment: The cardinality is 4 since the only elements are 1, 5, 7, 11 so each one has a degree of at most 4? That's not right because each one has a degree of two, but I'm not sure how the cardinality explains that.

Comment: @chris You seem to have forgotten that $2\leq 4$...

Comment: oh man, that was a stupid oversight. thanks

Comment: @chris No problem. If are more careful we can even see that every element has order $2$ by noting that this group is $C_2\time C_2$, thoughts thus point we are risking circularity because I’m not sure how you would find that decomposition without knowing the orders if all the elements already.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fine justification, but the true reason is that $5$ and $12$ are coprime, so by *Euler's theorem*, $5^{\varphi(12)}\equiv 1\mod 12$, and it happens that
$$\varphi(12)=\varphi(3)\cdot\varphi(4)=2\cdot 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct.

$5^2 = 1 \pmod {12}\\
1^2 = 1 \pmod {12}\\
5^4 = 1^2 = 1 \pmod {12}$

But if you want to get fancy you can invoke the Fermat-Euler theorem.

The set of numbers less than $12$ that are co-prime to $12$ form a cyclic group under multiplication modulo $12$.

There are 4 elements to this group.

Any element element in this group raised to the $4^{th}$ power equals the identity element.

More generally:

If $n$ has prime factorization $p_1^ip_2^j\cdots p_k^t$

$\phi(n) = n \frac {p_1 - 1}{p_1}\frac {p_2 - 1}{p_2}\cdots \frac {p_k - 1}{p_k}$

$\phi(n)$ is the number of elements co-prime to $n$

and if $\gcd (a,n) = 1$

$a^{\phi(n)} = 1 \pmod n$